# Install postgresql. Unmet dependencie " postgresql-common"

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to install postgis on Ubuntu 13.04. I've attempted to follow a number of different blogs and wikis on line, but always run in to the same problem...

```
$sudo apt-get install postgis postgresql-9.1-postgis
....
Package postgresql-9.2-postgis is not available, but is referred to by another
package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'postgresql-9.2-postgis' has no installation candidate
```

So I try 9.1...

```
$sudo apt-get install postgis postgresql-9.1-postgis
....
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
postgresql-9.1-postgis : Depends: postgresql-9.1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

No luck, so I go looking for postgresql-9.1...

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1
...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-9.1 : Depends: postgresql-common (>= 115~) but it is not going to be
 installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So postgresql-common then?

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-common : Breaks: logrotate (>= 3.8) but 3.8.3-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @nickanor Afraid not, I've tried that and there's no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you that although will not resolve the package problems it will hopefully give you a working postgresql system.

First, uninstall all installed postgresql packages - and I mean both clients and server.

Now download from [here](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload) the appropriate EnterpeiseDB installer for your system.

Run the installer and you will get a clean postgresql distribution including clients in /opt. You can then select additional software to install through the stackbuilder gui (odbc/jdbc drivers, replication, even an instance of apache web server) The installer also creates a uninstall script, so removing everything is a piece of cake.

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, stackbuilder even contains postgis, so I think I have everything I need now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not occur in my system... The package info for `logrotate`
says that it breaks `postgresql-common` for versions less than 1.26, but
the current version of `postgresql-common` is 1.40 (so it is not affected).

I assume your system is **not** up to date so try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Then try `sudo apt-get install postgis`.

If this doesn't work, try removing PostgreSQL if you have it installed and do `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgis`. Notice that you only need to install `postgresql-9.1-postgis` if you are using `postgresql-9.1` (which is not the Ubuntu 'default' package for PostgreSQL). It would be a good idea to show us which version of PostgreSQL you have installed.

Comment: I don't have any version of postgresql installed. <code>apt-get remove postgresql</code> confirms that, unless it's called something else. (and it's a brand new install of Ubuntu13.04 so I'd remember if I'd installed it)

Comment: Then you should try updating your system and then installing `postgis` as said in the second paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ring Tail, try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.0-scripts
```

Source: http://gingerjoos.com/blog/code/installing-postgis-on-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail

I know this is better suited as a comment, but requires 50 rep!